# What is the viewport size for the Iphone 5/Iphone 6/Iphone 7/Iphone X

Tags: ios, iphone, viewport, screen-size

## Introduction

Although this question might seem outright lazy at first glance, it is actually quite bothersome (e.g. the Iphone X's notch height being included in viewport calculation - information that is not mentioned anywhere else).

After fumbling around for a whole week and getting conflicting information from different websites, I decided just to go to the apple store and take a bunch of pictures of the website http://viewportsizes.com/mine/

I hope these rudimentary photos will help any future developers who are struggling with supporting different screen sizes.

## 1) Iphone X

[image]

## 2) Iphone 6 and 6+ (Iphone 7 and 7+ have same sizes)

[image]

## 3) Iphone 5

[image]

Comment: It is better to add source code as well. Also this is not a question but an information so better to find some question which require this answer and post it there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Additional browser (not screen) viewports:**

Iphone XS (same as iphone X): *375 x 635*

Iphone XS Max: *414 x 719*

Iphone 4: *320 x 372*